# проблема вывода из list box данных при множественном выборе

Tags: c#

Добавляю дынные в лист бокс через data source.при множественном выборе необходимо занести в коллекцию.При выводе получаем одно и то же значение пару раз

```
List<string> comission = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < listBox2.Items.Count; i++) 
{
    if (listBox2.GetSelected(i) == true ) 
    {
        comission.Add(listBox2.SelectedValue.ToString()); ;
    }
}

foreach (string ar in comission) 
{
    label3.Text += ar + "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что Вы добавляете всегда одно и то же значение, лежащее в [`SelectedValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx), которое зависит от [`SelectedItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx), в котором всегда лежит первый выбранный элемент или `null`, если не выбрано ничего. Воспользуйтесь свойством [`SelectedItems`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selecteditems(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
List<string> comission = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in listBox2.SelectedItems)
{
    comission.Add(item.ToString());
}

foreach (string ar in comission) 
{
    label3.Text += ar + "\n";
}
```

Само собой, можно обойтись одним `foreach`.

Если нужно делать именно через `for` - используйте свойство `Items`. Тогда строка добавления изменится на:

```
comission.Add(listBox2.Items[i].ToString());
```

Comment: System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal вот что выводит

Comment: ListBox заполняется из базы? Какие привязки идут?

Comment: listBox2.DataSource = dl.GetAllCommission();
            listBox2.DisplayMember = "fio";
            listBox2.ValueMember = "id";

Comment: `comission.Add((listBox2.Items[i] as DbDataRecord).Items["fio"]);` - так работает?

Comment: к сожалению нет

Comment: Я исправлял комментарий, посмотрите этот вариант.

Comment: Ошибка CS1061 'DbDataRecord" не содержит определения для "Items" и не удалось найти метод расширения "Items", принимающий тип "DbDataRecord" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку).

Comment: Тфьу, [Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/td7ywhk6(v=vs.110).aspx) конечно же!

Comment: Ошибка CS1061 'DbDataRecord" не содержит определения для "item" и не удалось найти метод расширения "item", принимающий тип "DbDataRecord" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку). SecGak

Comment: С заглавной буквы.

Comment: А он все равно говорит что так что эдак. нету такого

Comment: Я уже все перепробовал, так и не могу получить значения. При выборе одного элемента мой вариант работает. А вот при множественном отказывается

Comment: Ок, ну вот так он просто обязан сработать: `comission.Add((listBox2.Items[i] as DbDataRecord)["fio"])`

Comment: Ну вот сейчас точно заработал! Спасибо вам большое!